# How to access a vector of pointers based on this example?

Tags: c++

There are several similar questions but unfortunately, I couldn't find my answer..

I am trying to access the information based on the example below but I cannot seem to be able to get the values that I would be expecting. What is the correct way to get the information? Here is a simplified example:

```
#define T 8

using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::vector<float _Complex *> in;

    in.resize(T);

    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++)
    {
        in[i] = new float _Complex[64];

        for (int j = 0; j < 64; j++)
        {
            in[i][j] = 555;
            cout << in[i][j] << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"I cannot seem to be able to get the values that I would be expecting"_ is not a problem description... what values did you expect? what did you get instead?

Comment: There is a cout statement in the code, I want it to print the information that were put from rand. As an example imagine the rand is 6 so I would expect it to print 6.

Comment: `#define T 8` -- I see absolutely no way this could possibly go wrong.

Comment: @Quentin Why do you say that? Is T reserved or something?

Comment: @Quentin this is just example code I simplified quickly but indeed, what is wrong with it other than a bad practise in actual code?

Comment: Please explain to me... What is the point of imagining or expecting anything from a random number generator?

Comment: @Zebrafish macros are generally named with long, scary identifiers to avoid collisions. If I had to name a single-letter identifier that is *everywhere* in C++ code, that would be `T` ;)

Comment: @Jarod42 I am aware of that thank you but how would I access the information rand put?

Comment: @George just use a `const int`, that'll be plenty good for both the example and production code.

Comment: @underscore_d my main issue is to see the information placed for my personal understanding as I am new in C++. I do not care what rand puts in as long as I can see the value it put in it. How do I get that value? Clearly in[i][j] doesn't do what I would expect it to. Thank you.

Comment: OT: in C++ you can use [std::complex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) . More on topic, why don't you use a vector of vectors?

Comment: @Bob__ Thank you, could you also please provide a working example based on my code above? Specifically replacing the line where I have cout. cheers

Comment: @Bob__ In terms of your secondary question, it is simply for my understanding. I have a code with this complex usage that I need to extend and modify but I have to keep that style unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your mistake:
cout << float _Complex

Solution: If you want to use a specific type, you can do a [type alias](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias)

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <complex.h>

#define T 2

using namespace std;
using Complex = float _Complex; // C++11

int main() {
    std::vector<Complex *> in;

    in.resize(T);

    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++)
    {
        in[i] = new Complex[64];

        for (int j = 0; j < 64; j++)
        {
            in[i][j] = i*j;
            cout << creal(in[i][j]) << " + " << cimag(in[i][j]) << "i" << endl;

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you please explain why "float _Complex *" is wrong?

Comment: @George What is _Complex? I looked it up there's no such type

Comment: It is being used in a benchmark program that I try to modify. This simplified example works on my computer without the need of extra libraries and similarly the benchmark program which uses it. Based on what I have found on the internet: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types#Complex_floating_types

Comment: The problem is perhaps due to mutual usage of C langage (float _Complex) and C++ langage (std::vector). C++ version of complex number is for your program test : std::complex<float>

Comment: @Ratah Even in C it's supposed to be float complex, not _Complex, according to that link.

Comment: Of course, I'm not very C but it's just a problem of std::cout. try printf("%f + i*%f\n", creal(in[i][j]), cimag(in[i][j])); Don't forget to include <stdio.h>

Comment: AH! I didn't think of that! That is a very good point, I will give it a try as soon as I can and report back.

Comment: That worked, thank you.